# Looking for a Cocoa (Mac OS X) event that occurs when the window becomes deactivated

Tags: cocoa, macos, event-handling

I read that that class `NSWindows` has some of its own events, but I could not find a list of all them.  I believe there is an event that occurs when the window becomes deactivated.

Does such an event exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification** notification, but it's not Event.

Or in NSWindow subclass overload the **-(void)resignKeyWindow** method.

Answer (score 4):

Events and notifications are two different things, but you probably want *[NSWindowDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW18)*.